# Text file number to Python number how?

Tags: python

I have a problem with the fact that when I open a file and import a line with command f.readline ().I run the module then It works good. It shows the number 600 or it doesn't matter what number it is. But how I can get that number to be used in further calculations? When I type the next calculation command, it says something like for command int it should be a string or a number. But how I turn that text file number to number that I can calculate with and Python understands?

```
from math import *

with open('C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\terehommik.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        s = f.readline()
```

and from that line comes the number, and now i need to convert string number to real number
so i could after calculate with bank rate

Comment: Code or didn't happen.

Comment: Improve the code formatting. Add a sample of 2-3 lines from your file. If you expect someone to spend time helping you, spend some time to write a decent question.

Comment: Also, you already have the `line` when you do the `for loop`. No need to do `f.readline()`

Comment: Huh. TIL that Python actually checks for this case and throws `ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data`

Comment: What's in your input file?  One number per line, I'm assuming?

Comment: Also, no-one cares what "it says something like". Copy and paste the entire error, in full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `int` function:

```python
x = int('600')

# x is now 600, can be used in computations
print x + 1  # No TypeError--prints 601
```

So,

```python
s = f.readline()
x = int(s)
y = x * 5  # etc.
```

ADDENDUM:

OP, does your input file contain one number per line?  That's what I'll assume for now.

```python
with open('myfile') as f:
    for line in f:
        x = int(line)
        print x+3
```

If the contents of `myfile` are:

```python
600
3
67
987
```

then the above code will work, printing:

```python
603
6
70
990
```

N.B., for floats, use the aptly named `float` function instead.

Comment: This is exactly what OP claims he is doing.

Comment: @Wooble: I read his question differently; sounded to me like he was reading in a string and directly trying to do arithmetic on it.  But agreed, it would've behooved him to write it more clearly and include a code sample.

Comment: x = int(s)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' - still comes this error

Comment: @JürgenLorenz Are we playing a puzzle game? Are you going to post any code or what?

Comment: It sounds to me like we would also benefit from seeing the line of the input file where the error occurs. For example, the code would fail if it tried to convert a blank space, or a text row of headers, to integers.

Comment: @abought Obviously something along these lines is the problem. Unfortunately until we see some input, we can only speculate. Or reach for our crystal balls of course.

Comment: @JürgenLorenz: ValueError means that your input is not string that represents a valid [base 10] number.  I'll edit my answer to include some new info which might help you out.  And thanks for updating your original Q to add more useful info.